# Random Sample data based on other columns using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random, group-by

I have a dataframe with 100 000 rows contains Country, State, bill_ID, item_id, dates etc... columns
I want to random sample 5k lines out of 100k lines which should have atleast one bill_ID from all countries and state.
In short it should cover all countries and states with atleast one bill_ID.

Note: bill_ID contains multiple item_id

I am doing testing on a sampled data which should cover all unique countries and states with there bill_IDs.

Comment: You should add a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)) that replicates your problem.

Comment: Please use universal measurements instead of local words like *lakh* that rest of the world does not use or understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Pandas' `.sample` method. With `df` your dataframe try:

```py
sample_size = 5_000
df_sample_1 = df.groupby(["Country", "State"]).sample(1)
sample_size_2 = max(sample_size - df_sample_1.shape[0], 0)
df_sample_2 = df.loc[df.index.difference(df_sample_1.index)].sample(sample_size_2)
df_sample = pd.concat([df_sample_1, df_sample_2]).sort_index()
```

First group by columns `Country` and `State` and draw samples of size 1. This gives you a sample `df_sample_1` that covers each `Country`-`State`-combination exactly once. Then draw the rest from the dataframe that doesn't contain the first sample: `df_sample_2`. Finally concatenate both samples (and sort the result if needed).